# What configuration settings are required in Django and MySQL for supporting concurrent requests?

Tags: python, mysql, django, concurrency

I have created a project called test123, following are settings.py and urls.py :

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'read_default_file': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dbuser.cnf'),
    }
},
}
root@cdbe25bac912:~/test123/test123# cat urls.py
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

And I have created an application called myapp.

```
root@cdbe25bac912:~/test123/myapp# cat models.py
from django.db import models

class Package(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   desc = models.CharField(max_length=50)
root@cdbe25bac912:~/test123/myapp# cat serializers.py
from myapp.models import *
from rest_framework import serializers

class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Package
    fields = ( 'id', 'name', 'desc',)

root@cdbe25bac912:~/test123/myapp# cat views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from myapp.models import *
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from myapp.serializers import *
class PackageViewList(APIView):
   def get(self, request, format=None):
       package = Package.objects.all()
       serializer = PackageSerializer(package, many=True)
       return Response(serializer.data)

   def post(self, request, format=None):
       serializer = PackageSerializer(data = request.data)
       if serializer.is_valid():
           print serializer.validated_data
           serializer.save()
           return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
       return Response(serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

root@cdbe25bac912:~/test123/myapp# cat urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^package/$', views.PackageViewList.as_view()),
]
root@cdbe25bac912:~/test123/myapp#
```

Following is a test script written using Django Test Framework, which creates multiple APIClient objects to simulate multiple users and fire POST operation from these objects.

```
root@cdbe25bac912:~/test123/myapp# cat tests.py.bkup
from django.test import TestCase
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, APILiveServerTestCase
from myapp.models import Package
from multiprocessing import Process

class ConcurrentTest(APILiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.apiclient_list = []
        self.num_clients=4

        package = Package.objects.create(name='pack333', desc='package333')
        package.save()
        self.pack = {"name" : "pack", "desc" : "package"}

       #create number of APIClient objects and login.
        for client_id in range(self.num_clients):
                apiclient = APIClient()
                self.apiclient_list.append(apiclient)

    def post(self, apiclient, client_id, url, data):
        print 'Started POST Client ID = %s' % (str(client_id))
        data['name'] = 'packpost' + str(client_id)
        data['desc'] = 'packdesc' + str(client_id)
        print data
        response = apiclient.post(url, data, format="json")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
        print 'Completed POST Client ID = %s' % (str(client_id))
   def test_concurrent_restops(self):
    """
    Description : Simulate multiple users and issue concurrent REST operations
    """
    process_list = []

    #Issue concurrent POST operations.
    for client_id in range(len(self.apiclient_list)):
        t = Process(target=self.post, args=(self.apiclient_list[client_id], client_id, '/myapp/package/', self.pack))
        process_list.append(t)

    for process in process_list :
        process.start()
    for process in process_list :
        process.join()
```

root@cdbe25bac912:~/test123/myapp#

### Problem symptoms:

When I run the above test problem as: `python manage.py test myapp`

At least one of the processes that are created in `test.py` will hang. I am assuming there are some configurations required in Django and MySQL to support concurrent operations from different users.

Comment: However, If I run the same test with SQLite3, it works fine. Also with MySQL if the operations are triggered sequentially, it fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `LiveServerTestCase` is single threaded which would explain why processes/requests hang, because the server can only service a single request at a time:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/53ccffdb8c8e47a4d4304df453d8c79a9be295ab/django/test/testcases.py#L1319

https://github.com/django/django/blob/53ccffdb8c8e47a4d4304df453d8c79a9be295ab/django/test/testcases.py#L1332

https://github.com/django/django/blob/53ccffdb8c8e47a4d4304df453d8c79a9be295ab/django/test/testcases.py#L1255

---

One thing i can think of why you aren't seeing blocking using sqlite is because sqlite is ran in memory for django unittest, drastically increasing speeds of test runs.

Django `LiveServerTestServer` is kind of a "toy" and is probably not very suitable for load style tests. MySQL should easily be able to handle a good level of concurrency out-of-the box, but I'm not sure `LiveServerTestServer` can.

If you run your code against `python manage.py runserver` which is now multithreaded (I believe) you should notice a difference.  For an idea of how your application can handle load, it could be a good idea run your code as it will be deployed (using your prod webserver: apache, uwsgi, gunicorn, etc..)